# Can you receive ultra balls from Pokestops?

Tags: pokemon-go

After getting level 20 I was rewarded with 20 ultra balls (among other stuff). I assume this would have been like with the great balls, which unlocked them and allowed you to collect them from pokestops.

However after getting about 30-50 pokestops after hitting level 20, I have yet to get a single ultra ball, am I just incredibly unlucky?

Is it possible to get ultra balls from pokestops or is it going to be a pay to get item like lures and lucky eggs?

Comment: I feel your pain - I'm still yet to receive one and am almost on level 21!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Source: I have. They aren't as common as regular balls. Don't forget to curve those when you run out of ultras.

Comment: I finally got one, seems like it's a crazy low chance. What do you mean by curving regular balls?

Comment: Swirl your finger when "holding" a pokeball and then throw it to get the curveball bonus!

Comment: I know how to get a curveball bonus. But why did you say to curve normal balls when run out of ultras?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can. I just hit 20 after egg evolve strategy and I spin pokestop for the FIRST time and I get an ultra ball. I was very surprised and wanted to know how rare these actually are. So I know you CAN get them from pokestops but no idea about the chance. I wish I was this lucky with the egg hatches...

Comment: After getting quite a lot more pokestops (and ultra balls) I'd say the chance is probably around 1-5%

Answer (score 1):

Yup, they definently do!
They are a bit rare to drop though.
Here are some screenshots from a lucky day:

[image: Ultra Balls at a PokéStop]

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqD8h.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can get ultra balls from Pokestops.

Source:[Pokemon Get up and Go trailer](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Qryf2F_QfXg)

In this trailer, a woman spins the pokestop and gets ultra pokeballs from it.

Comment: A trailer does not necessarily mean it is in the game. Content has been shown in trailers, but cut from the game due to differant reasons, before.

Comment: @Timelord64 I didn't see any content which is not in the game. Trading and battling will other players will be added in the future updates.

Comment: In other words, you *did* see content that is not *yet* in the game. It also does show pre-release content that has been changed; *Psyduck evolves at 50 candys, not 21*